# Idiomatic C++11 type promotion

Tags: c++, c++11, type-promotion

There is [a great paper](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/pub/techreports/TR542.pdf) on C++ for scientific computing where the author (T. Veldhuizen) suggests a *traits-based* approach to address type promotion. I have used such approach, and found it effective:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<complex>
#include<typeinfo>

template<typename T1, typename T2>
struct promote_trait{};

#define DECLARE_PROMOTION(A, B, C) template<> struct promote_trait<A, B> { using T_promote = C;};

DECLARE_PROMOTION(int, char, int);
DECLARE_PROMOTION(int, float, float);
DECLARE_PROMOTION(float, std::complex<float>, std::complex<float>);

// similarly for all possible type combinations...

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void product(T1 a, T2 b) {
  using T = typename promote_trait<T1, T2>::T_promote;
  T ans = T(a) * T(b);  
  std::cout<<"received "
           <<typeid(T1).name()<<"("<<a<<")"<<" * "
           <<typeid(T2).name()<<"("<<b<<")"<<" ==> "
           <<"returning "
           <<typeid(T).name()<<"("<<ans<<")"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
  product(1, 'a');
  product(1, 2.0f);
  product(1.0f, std::complex<float>(1.0f, 2.0f));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
received i(1) * c(a) ==> returning i(97)
received i(1) * f(2) ==> returning f(2)
received f(1) * St7complexIfE((1,2)) ==> returning St7complexIfE((1,2))
```

*the name of the types returned by typeinfo is implementation dependent; your output may differ from mine, which used GCC 4.7.2 on OS X 10.7.4*

In essence, the approach defines a `promote_trait` which contains simply one type definition: the type to which two types should be promoted when operating in a given manner. One needs to declare all possible promotions.

When one function receives both types, it relies on the `promote_trait` to deduce the correct, promoted type of the result. If a trait has not been defined for a given pair the code fails to compile (a desirable feature).

Now, the paper in question was written in 2000, and we know that C++ has evolved dramatically over the past decade. My question, then, is the following:

**Is there a modern, idiomatic C++ 11 approach to dealing with type promotion as effective as the traits-based approach introduced by Veldhuizen?**

## Edit (on using `std::common_type`)

Based on Luc Danton's suggestion, I created the following code which uses `std::common_type`:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<complex>
#include<typeinfo>
#include<typeindex>
#include<string>
#include<utility>
#include<map>

// a map to homogenize the type names across platforms
std::map<std::type_index, std::string> type_names = {
  {typeid(char)                 , "char"},  
  {typeid(int)                  , "int"},
  {typeid(float)                , "float"},
  {typeid(double)               , "double"},
  {typeid(std::complex<int>)    , "complex<int>"},
  {typeid(std::complex<float>)  , "complex<float>"},
  {typeid(std::complex<double>) , "complex<double>"},
};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void promotion(T1 a, T2 b) {
  std::string T1name = type_names[typeid(T1)];
  std::string T2name = type_names[typeid(T2)];
  std::string TPname = type_names[typeid(typename std::common_type<T1, T2>::type)];  
  std::cout<<T1name<<"("<<a<<") and "<<T2name<<"("<<b<<") promoted to "<<TPname<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
  promotion(1, 'a');
  promotion(1, 1.0);
  promotion(1.0, 1);
  promotion(std::complex<double>(1), 1);
  promotion(1.0f, 1);
  promotion(1.0f, 1.0);
  promotion(std::complex<int>(1), std::complex<double>(1));
  promotion(std::complex<double>(1), std::complex<int>(1));
  promotion(std::complex<float>(0, 2.0f), std::complex<int>(1));

  return 0;
}
```

with output:

```
int(1) and char(a) promoted to int
int(1) and double(1) promoted to double
double(1) and int(1) promoted to double
complex<double>((1,0)) and int(1) promoted to complex<double>
float(1) and int(1) promoted to float
float(1) and double(1) promoted to double
complex<int>((1,0)) and complex<double>((1,0)) promoted to complex<int>
complex<double>((1,0)) and complex<int>((1,0)) promoted to complex<int>
complex<float>((0,2)) and complex<int>((1,0)) promoted to complex<int>
```

I am surprised to notice that all but the last three promotions are what I expected. Why would `complex<int>` and `complex<double>` or `complex<float>` be promoted to `complex<int>`!?

Comment: Are you familiar with `std::common_type`?

Comment: @LucDanton: very, very useful. I am surprised, however, about the type promotion between `std::complex<int>` and `std::complex<float>` and `std::complex<double>`. Any insight?

Comment: This is presumably due to the primary template of `std::complex`, and speaking of: "The effect of instantiating the template complex for any type other than float, double, or long double is unspecified."

Comment: @Arrieta, what is the rule you find with `commn_type`? Take into account that `common_type` doesn't necessarely know about the product operation, it just a "protocol" for conversion. For example if one type is in meter units and the other type is time units, `common_type` can not help in determining the product result (decltype can in principle do it, but that is another story)

Comment: @LucDanton: That is exactly the answer - it is not being promoted to `complex<int>`. Instead, it is the realization of an undefined behavior. I'm surprised gcc did not issue warnings (even with the `-Wall` flag)...

Comment: @alfC FTR the associated expression of e.g. `std::common_type<T, U>` is `true ? t : u` (where `t` and `u` have respective types `T` and `U`), which I've found useful in the past. E.g. expressing the return type of `maybe(optional<T>, U);`. You're absolutely right that this trait only makes sense for 'homogeneous' types.

Comment: Do note that the effects are *unspecified*, not undefined. So the program is non-portable, but not necessarily incorrect. It might be the case that the libstdc++ implementation of `std::complex<int>` is usable (except perhaps for that quirk with `std::common_type`).

Answer (score 5):

As in catscradle answer, `decltype` and `common_type` (and custom specializations for it), are probably good C++11 replacement for the need of conversion traits that Veldhuizen have in mind. However, it will still fall short if you need to be still *very* specific for the evaluation of a function that maps two types into one (binary operator). (In other words `decltype` doesn't know about the mathematical domain of your problem).

My take is that you can resort to Boost.MPL maps http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/map.html, this doesn't even require C++11, it is just that MPL wasn't written at that time:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<complex>
#include<typeinfo>
#include <boost/mpl/map.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/at.hpp>
// all traits in one place, no need for MACROS or C++11, compile error if the case does not exist.
using namespace boost::mpl;
typedef map<
    pair<pair<int, char>, int>,
    pair<pair<int, float>, int>,
    pair<pair<float, std::complex<float> >, std::complex<float> >
> mapped_promotion;

template<typename T1, typename T2>
void product(T1 a, T2 b) {
  typedef typename at<mapped_promotion, pair<T1, T2> >::type T;

  T ans = T(a) * T(b);  
  std::cout<<"received "
           <<typeid(T1).name()<<"("<<a<<")"<<" * "
           <<typeid(T2).name()<<"("<<b<<")"<<" ==> "
           <<"returning "
           <<typeid(T).name()<<"("<<ans<<")"<<std::endl;
}

int main() {
  product(1, 'a');
  product(1, 2.0f);
  product(1.0f, std::complex<float>(1.0f, 2.0f));
  return 0;
}
```

Another extra benefit of using MPL is that you can then easily move to `Boost.Fusion` later, which usually is the case once you start dealing with "algebras" of types. And there is nothing to replace the functionality of Boost.Fusion in C++11 core language.

---

What follows is a more general solution, you can stop reading if the above was enough for your application, that combines MPL and `decltype` and requires C++11 which allows for unspecified pair of types to default to the decltype solution if it is any good, the trick is to see if the return of the `mpl::map` is the metatype `void_` (pair not found).

```
...
#include <type_traits> 
//specific promotions
using namespace boost::mpl;
typedef map<
    pair<pair<int, char>, int>,
    pair<pair<int, float>, int>,
    pair<pair<float, std::complex<float> >, std::complex<float> >
> specific_mapped_promotion;

//promotion for unspecified combinations defaults to decltype type deduction.
template<class P1, class P2>
struct loose_mapped_promotion : std::conditional<
    std::is_same<typename at<specific_mapped_promotion, pair<P1, P2> >::type, mpl_::void_>::value,
    decltype( std::declval<P1>()*std::declval<P2>() ),
    typename at<specific_mapped_promotion, pair<P1, P2> >::type
> {};
template<typename T1, typename T2>
void product(T1 a, T2 b) {
  typedef typename loose_mapped_promotion<T1, T2>::type T;

  T ans = T(a) * T(b);
  ...
}
int main() {
   product(1.0, std::complex<double>(1.0f, 2.0f)); // now accepted, although no explicit trait was made
}
```

On a final note: it is apparently ok to overload `std::common_type` for special cases, if you want to use it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/common_type/

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use `decltype` for this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
void product(T t, U u) 
{
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(t * u)).name() << std::endl;
}
```

Or with `declval`:

```
#include <utility>
template <typename T, typename U>
void product() 
{
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(std::declval<T>() * std::declval<U>())).name() << std::endl;
}
```

**EDIT** For `T ans = T(a) * T(b);` you can just use `auto`, `auto ans = T(a) * T(b);`

Comment: This is completely not at all equivalent to what the OP has.

Comment: @DeadMG, I agree, it covers some of the practical need for `promote_traits` but it is not a replacement.

Comment: @DeadMG: No, it's not equivalent.  It's better.  The difference between two pointers is an integer not a pointer.  And many other cases where a `common_type`-like method fails.

Comment: Both `common_type` and `decltype` are not enough to provide an equivalent feature.

Comment: A hand-written template might help in handling things like the surprising `-1 > 0U`, where `common_type` and `decltype` don't get you any farther at all.