# Is it possible to calculate the return type of a Rust function or trait method based on its arguments?

Tags: arguments, rust, type-promotion

Can I achieve something similar to [`boost::math::tools::promote_args`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/boost/math/tools/promotion.hpp) in Rust? See also [Idiomatic C++11 type promotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16865376/idiomatic-c11-type-promotion)

To be more specific: is it possible to calculate the return type of a function or trait method based on its arguments and ensure, that the return type has the same type as one of the arguments?

Consider the following case. I have two structs:

```
#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct MySimpleType(f64);

#[derive(Debug, Clone, Copy)]
struct MyComplexType(f64, f64);
```

where `MySimpleType` can be promoted to `MyComplexType` via the `From` trait.

```
impl From<MySimpleType> for MyComplexType {
    fn from(src: MySimpleType) -> MyComplexType {
        let MySimpleType(x1) = src;
        MyComplexType(x1, 0.0)
    }
 }
```

I want to write a function that takes two arguments of types `MySimpleType` or `MyComplexType` and return a value of type `MySimpleType` if all arguments are typed as `MySimpleType`, otherwise the function should return a value of type `MyComplexType`. Assuming I have implemented `Add<Output=Self>` for both types I could do something like this:

```
trait Foo<S, T> {
    fn foo(s: S, t: T) -> Self;
}

impl<S, T, O> Foo<S, T> for O
    where O: From<S> + From<T> + Add<Output = Self>
{
    fn foo(s: S, t: T) -> Self {
        let s: O = From::from(s);
        let t: O = From::from(t);
        s + t
    }
}
```

but then the compiler doesn't know that `O` should be either `S` or `T` and I have to annotate most method calls.

My second attempt is to use a slightly different trait and write two implementations:

```
trait Foo<S, T> {
    fn foo(s: S, t: T) -> Self;
}

impl Foo<MySimpleType, MySimpleType> for MySimpleType {
    fn foo(s: MySimpleType, t: MySimpleType) -> Self {
        s + t
    }
}

impl<S, T> Foo<S, T> for MyComplexType
    where MyComplexType: From<S> + From<T>
{
    fn foo(s: S, t: T) -> Self {
        let s: MyComplexType = From::from(s);
        let t: MyComplexType = From::from(t);
        s + t
    }
}
```

but again, the compiler isn't able to figure the return type of

```
Foo::foo(MySimpleType(1.0), MySimpleType(1.0))
```

The third attempt is something similar to the `std::ops::{Add, Mul, ...}`. Use an associated type and write a specific implementation for each possible combination of argument types

```
trait Foo<T> {
    type Output;
    fn foo(self, t: T) -> Self::Output;
}

impl<T: Add<Output=T>> Foo<T> for T {
    type Output = Self;
    fn foo(self, t: T) -> Self::Output {
        self + t
    }
}

impl Foo<MySimpleType> for MyComplexType {
    type Output = Self;
    fn foo(self, t: MySimpleType) -> Self::Output {
        let t: Self = From::from(t);
        self + t
    }
}

impl Foo<MyComplexType> for MySimpleType {
    type Output = MyComplexType;
    fn foo(self, t: MyComplexType) -> Self::Output {
        let s: MyComplexType = From::from(self);
        s + t
    }
}
```

This seems to be the best solution until one needs a function with `n` arguments. Because then one has to write `2^n - n + 1` `impl` statements. Of course, this gets even worse if more then two types being considered.

===

Edit:

In my code I've multiple nested function calls and I want to avoid non necessary type promotion, since the evaluation of the functions for the simple type is cheap and expensive for the complex type. By using @MatthieuM. 's proposed solution, this is not achieved. Please consider the following example

```
#![feature(core_intrinsics)]

use std::ops::Add;

trait Promote<Target> {
    fn promote(self) -> Target;
}

impl<T> Promote<T> for T {
    fn promote(self) -> T {
        self
    }
}

impl Promote<u64> for u32 {
    fn promote(self) -> u64 {
        self as u64
    }
}

fn foo<Result, Left, Right>(left: Left, right: Right) -> Result
    where Left: Promote<Result>,
        Right: Promote<Result>,
        Result: Add<Output = Result>
{
    println!("============\nFoo called");
    println!("Left: {}", unsafe { std::intrinsics::type_name::<Left>() });
    println!("Right: {}",
            unsafe { std::intrinsics::type_name::<Right>() });
    println!("Result: {}",
            unsafe { std::intrinsics::type_name::<Result>() });
    left.promote() + right.promote()
}

fn bar<Result, Left, Right>(left: Left, right: Right) -> Result
    where Left: Promote<Result>,
        Right: Promote<Result>,
        Result: Add<Output = Result>
{
    left.promote() + right.promote()
}

fn baz<Result, A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) -> Result
    where A: Promote<Result>,
        B: Promote<Result>,
        C: Promote<Result>,
        D: Promote<Result>,
        Result: Add<Output = Result>
{
    let lhs = foo(a, b).promote();
    let rhs = bar(c, d).promote();
    lhs + rhs
}

fn main() {
    let one = baz(1u32, 1u32, 1u64, 1u32);
    println!("{}", one);
}
```

Comment: _"until one needs a function with n arguments"_ – Did you consider writing a macro to generate the necessary traits on-demand?

Comment: I’ve considered to use a macro, but I’m curious if another solution exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect the simplest way to implement promotion is to create a `Promote` trait:

```
trait Promote<Target> {
    fn promote(self) -> Target;
}

impl<T> Promote<T> for T {
    fn promote(self) -> T { self }
}
```

*Note: I provide a blanket implementation as all types can be promoted to themselves.*

Using associated types is NOT an option here, because a single type can be promoted to multiple types; thus we just use a regular type parameter.

---

Using this, a simple example is:

```
impl Promote<u64> for u32 {
    fn promote(self) -> u64 { self as u64 }
}

fn add<Result, Left, Right>(left: Left, right: Right) -> Result
    where
        Left: Promote<Result>,
        Right: Promote<Result>,
        Result: Add<Output = Result>
{
    left.promote() + right.promote()
}

fn main() {
    let one: u32 = add(1u32, 1u32);
    let two: u64 = add(1u32, 2u64);
    let three: u64 = add(2u64, 1u32);
    let four: u64 = add(2u64, 2u64);
    println!("{} {} {} {}", one, two, three, four);
}
```

The only issue is that in the case of two `u32` arguments, the result type must be specified otherwise the compiler cannot choose between which possible `Promote` implementation to use: `Promote<u32>` or `Promote<u64>`.

I am not sure if this is an issue in practice, however, since at some point you should have a concrete type to anchor type inference. For example:

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![add(1u32, 1u32), add(1u32, 2u64)];
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

compiles without type hint, because `add(1u32, 2u64)` can only be `u64`, and therefore since a `Vec` is a homogeneous collection, `add(1u32, 1u32)` has to return a `u64` here.

---

As you experienced, though, sometimes you need the ability to direct the result beyond what type inference can handle. It's fine, you just need another trait for it:

```
trait PromoteTarget {
    type Output;
}

impl<T> PromoteTarget for (T, T) {
    type Output = T;
}
```

And then a little implementation:

```
impl PromoteTarget for (u32, u64) {
    type Output = u64;
}

impl PromoteTarget for (u64, u32) {
    type Output = u64;
}
```

With that out of the way, we can rewrite `baz` signature to correctly account for all intermediate types. Unfortunately I don't know any way to introduce aliases in a `where` clause, so brace yourself:

```
fn baz<Result, A, B, C, D>(a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D) -> Result
    where
        A: Promote<<(A, B) as PromoteTarget>::Output>,
        B: Promote<<(A, B) as PromoteTarget>::Output>,
        C: Promote<<(C, D) as PromoteTarget>::Output>,
        D: Promote<<(C, D) as PromoteTarget>::Output>,
        (A, B): PromoteTarget,
        (C, D): PromoteTarget,
        <(A, B) as PromoteTarget>::Output: Promote<Result> + Add<Output = <(A, B) as PromoteTarget>::Output>,
        <(C, D) as PromoteTarget>::Output: Promote<Result> + Add<Output = <(C, D) as PromoteTarget>::Output>,
        Result: Add<Output = Result>
{
    let lhs = foo(a, b).promote();
    let rhs = bar(c, d).promote();
    lhs + rhs
}
```

Link to the playground [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=06704759e697755695b9a7b0c5bd7c1c&version=nightly&backtrace=0), so you can check the result:

> ```
> ============
> Foo called
> Left: u32
> Right: u32
> Result: u32
> 4
> ```

Comment: *et tu*, Matthieu? You've switched to the block-style indent for where clauses?

Comment: What's the difference of `Promote` and [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html)?

Comment: @Shepmaster: (1) I'm trying to get used to this block-style indent thing, (2) I used `Promote` to demonstrate the concept because it was easier to hack in; it started a fairly bit different and I didn't realize it was now matching `Into` to be honest. I'm also not sure it's exactly what the OP wants... or that type inference will not be insufficient.

Comment: There's also a benefit in that *this crate* can then define promotions for standard library types, although I guess `From` is implemented for widening integer conversions (was it always?)

Comment: @Shepmaster: I guess the main annoying point with `From` is around promoting to `usize`: it's only implemented for `u8` in case you would be fiddling around on an 8-bits architecture. So indeed, with a custom trait, you get the opportunity to convert to `usize` for more types... but it really an incidental property :)

Comment: Which also means you get to write code that's less portable ;-) As someone who wants to write Rust for the AVR, I'm ok with that at times.

Comment: @MatthieuM. thank you for your answer. The problem I’m facing consists of multiple nested function / trait method calls, of which each take the simple or promoted type as arguments. Evaluating the function is cheap for the simple type but expensive for the promoted/complex type. Thus, I would like to avoid the promotion if possible. I'll add an illustrative example to my question.

Comment: @wiep: I think the modelling of `baz` is incorrect. You would need to have a different result type for `foo` and `bar`, and have *those* types be `Promote<Result>`. I'm not surprised it came up, though. Time for v2...

Comment: @MatthieuM. : you're right. `baz` might need two additional type parameters for the intermediate results that implement `Promote<Result>` and `Add` and for which `A, B: Promete<IntermediateResultLeft>` and `C, D: Promete<IntermediateResultRight>` is satisfied. But then the compiler might need a hint. _Time for v2..._ does this mean i should ask a second question?

Comment: @wiep: Nope, just that I needed some time to work on the second iteration of my solution; to be honest, I kinda knew it would be insufficient since the beginning... but I also knew the second version was a significantly bulkier one so just in case it would have been sufficient. I've got it now, just let me edit it in.

Comment: @MatthieuM. v2 works nicely and is easily extensible for functions with more then two arguments. Thx! Of course it gets more tedious if more intermediate results are needed. I don't know how to introduce type aliases in where clauses, but you can use additional type parameter and assign them to the associated types. this cleans things a bit... see [this playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=4dca0d690e7a5b4cb1328b3236e31474&version=nightly&backtrace=0)

Comment: @wiep: Nice clean-up.